# Получить все URL страницы сайта (500+)

Tags: javascript, php, url

Доброе время суток господа. Подскажите как можно реализовать (желательно php, или js) или может уже реализована задача:
получить в файл все URL страницы сайта (создано более 500 страниц). Не зависимо от движка.

Comment: `document.links`

Comment: это так понимаю ссылки на открытой странице выведет, а мне нужны страницы всего сайта.

Comment: Есть такая штука, называется веб краулер (web crawler), к примеру - https://github.com/spatie/crawler. Её используют чтобы пройтись по всем ссылкам всех страниц сайта и сделать какие-либо действия с ними.

Comment: спасибо, заюзаю :)